# Spring boot profiles with external properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to setup 3 profiles in spring boot: production,development,test with using an external config file.

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

AppConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("config/application.yml"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${external.config}")
})

@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {

}
```

config/application.yml:

```
---
spring.profiles: production
endpoints.enabled: false
---
spring.profiles: development,test
endpoints.enabled: true
info.version: @project.version@
info.test: Test dev or test
info.profile: ${spring.profiles.active}
---

external.config: ${user.home}/.myapp/application.properties
```

.myapp/application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=production
info.version=5
```

The output of spring-boot-actuator /info

```
{
  version: "5",
  test: "Test dev or test",
  profile: "production"
}
```

Expected output:

```
404 because of the endpoints.enabled: false
```

The spring-boot-actuator /env

```
spring.profiles.active: "production"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably prefix the application.yml file with `classpath:`

In any case, why not just use the spring profile to drive configuration directly in java configuration? IMO, this would be cleaner and would make your properties more type-safe & re-factor friendly and not prone to spelling mistakes.

UPDATE:

According to the docs, you can't load yml files with the `@PropertySource` annotation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings

So if you need to use files, you'll need to use plain properties files. You could use property-specific application properties files shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

> In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific
>   properties can also be defined using the naming convention
>   application-{profile}.properties.

Comment: Hi, I also tried with classpath, It's also working without that. The ${external.config} works, btw the  version: "5" value come from external config. I also have a lot more properties at the external config eg.: database properties it's working.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Apologies. I see you can evaluate any config already registered against the env. I will update my answer.

Comment: I think using classpath: may be safer/more predicatable across different environments

Comment: Thanks, at the first time I thought that it will be easy. :( But the production profile settings why not be activated?

Comment: Ok, according to the docs, you can't load yml files with @PropertySource http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings

Comment: Finally it's working with:
@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource(value = "file:${user.home}/.myapp/application.properties"),
  @PropertySource(value = "config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
})


And  in ext config: spring.profiles.active=test

Thank you very much!